# Prevent extjs4's treegrid load data at the initialization

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm using the EXTJS4's tree grid (`Ext.tree.panel`).

I have create a model and treestore to load the tree data, and specified the store to the treegrid, the code is the following:

```
var complist = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    model: PFSComponent,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'getpfscomponents.php',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
});

var compPanel = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'lowdisks',
    height: 300,
    collapsible: false,
    useArrows: false,
    rootVisible: false,
    multiSelect: false,
    singleExpand: false,
    region: 'south',
    store: complist,
    columns: [{
        xtype: 'treecolumn', //this is so we know which column will show the tree
        text: 'name',
        flex: 2,
        sortable: false,
        dataIndex: 'name'
    }, {
        text: 'type',
        dataIndex: 'type',
        flex: 1,
        sortable: false
    }, {
        text: 'device',
        dataIndex: 'devicename',
        flex: 1,
        sortable: false
    }, {
        text: 'mount',
        dataIndex: 'mount',
        flex: 1,
        sortable: false
    }]
});
```

When the page load, the `treegrid` will load the data auto, it works very good!

But now I want to do something such as check the db, before the grid loaded.

So I need implement the functions like the following :

1. check whether the data is satisfied with the request
2. if it's , the `treegrid` load the data
3. or, alert the user

So my question is how to prevent the `treegrid` to load the data when `initialization`?

Thank you very much!

Comment: This thread may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843864/extjs-4-treepanel-autoload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `beforeload` event on your tree loader.. return `false` from the `beforeload` event if you want to cancel the tree loading. You can write the code for checking the DB here.